Making citations with many names display correctly in beamer
I want to cite references in a beamer presentation. When there are two many author names, it fails to display them correctly. The behavior can be replicated with the following very simple example.
% sample.tex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Simple}

\title[short title]{Simple Beamer Theme}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author[Albert] {Einstein}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \cite{example2024}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

% references.bib
@article{example2024,
  author = {First Author1 and Second Author2 and Third Author3 and Fourth Author4 and Fifth Author5},
  title = {Title of the Paper},
  journal = {Journal Name},
  year = {2024},
  volume = {1},
  number = {1},
  pages = {1-10}
}

When I compile the document, it displays the citation as:

[Author1 et al.(2024)Author1, Author2, Author3, Author4, and Author5]

which is obviously undesired.
Question: How do I display citations correctly in latex, showing all names (no et al.) and without the garbage output in front?

If you use a custom theme which is not included in the commonly available latex distributions, please always include a link to where we can get it from - in particular if it has such a common name and several very different versions of it float around the internet.

The undesirable-looking citation call-out issue is not related to the beamer document class. Instead, it's related to a failure to load the natbib citation management package.


If you want to use the natbib bibliography style plainnat, you should load the natbib package

If you would like to display all others without et al., you could use \citet*{...} etc.

Depending on which of the several Simple beamer themes floating around the internet you have, you might need \hypersetup{colorlinks=false} to avoid the broken colouring of the citations applied by the theme.



% sample.tex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Simple}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}

\title[short title]{Simple Beamer Theme}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author[Albert] {Einstein}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
% references.bib
@article{example2024,
  author = {First Author1 and Second Author2 and Third Author3 and Fourth Author4 and Fifth Author5},
  title = {Title of the Paper},
  journal = {Journal Name},
  year = {2024},
  volume = {1},
  number = {1},
  pages = {1-10}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \citet*{example2024}
\vfill
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



+1 for figuring out that the OP's issue was caused by the failure to load the natbib citation management package, and for posting suggesting both \citet and \citet* to generate citation call-outs.

@Mico Thanks! Do you happen to know if there is a dupe target? This can't be the first user with this problem, but I'm having trouble finding one.

I share your hunch that there should be an earlier posting that deals with the same issue, but I can't find a suitable posting either.
